# Entity framework throw exception while fetch DateTime

Tags: c#, entity-framework

I have ef core (on Postgres) model

```cs
    public class Price
    {
        public Price()
        {
        }

        public string OrderId { get; set; }

        public string Currency { get; set; }

        public decimal Amount { get; set; }

        public string Message { get; set; }

        public PriceType PriceType { get; set; } //  enum

        public DateTime SyncingOn { get; set; }

        [ConcurrencyCheck]
        public DateTimeOffset UpdatedOn { get; set; }
    }


    modelBuilder.Entity<Price>(z =>
            {
                z.ToTable(nameof(Price));
                z.HasKey(p => p.OrderId);
                z.Property(p => p.PriceType)
                 .IsRequired()
                 .HasConversion(v => v.ToString(),
                                v => (PriceType)Enum.Parse(typeof(PriceType), v));

            });
```

This model has one field with DateTime type. If I try to select that field, then EF throw exception

```
dbContext.Prices.ToList()
```

> System.ArgumentNullException: Value cannot be null.
>   Parameter name: method
>      at System.Linq.Expressions.Expression.Call(MethodInfo method, Expression arg0)
>      at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Metadata.Internal.EntityMaterializerSource.<>c__DisplayClass7_0.b__2(<>f__AnonymousType1`2 <>h__TransparentIdentifier0)
>      at System.Linq.Utilities.<>c__DisplayClass2_0`3.b__0(TSource x)
>      at System.Linq.Enumerable.SelectEnumerableIterator`2.MoveNext()
>      at System.Collections.Generic.List`1.AddEnumerable(IEnumerable`1 enumerable)
>      at System.Collections.Generic.List`1.InsertRange(Int32 index, IEnumerable`1 collection)
>      at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Metadata.Internal.EntityMaterializerSource.CreateMaterializeExpression(IEntityType entityType, Expression materializationExpression, Int32[] indexMap)
>      at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Query.ExpressionVisitors.Internal.MaterializerFactory.CreateMaterializer(IEntityType entityType, SelectExpression selectExpression, Func`3 projectionAdder, Dictionary`2& typeIndexMap)
>      at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Query.ExpressionVisitors.RelationalEntityQueryableExpressionVisitor.CreateShaper(Type elementType, IEntityType entityType, SelectExpression selectExpression)
>      at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Query.ExpressionVisitors.RelationalEntityQueryableExpressionVisitor.VisitEntityQueryable(Type elementType)
>      at System.Linq.Expressions.ConstantExpression.Accept(ExpressionVisitor visitor)
>      at System.Linq.Expressions.ExpressionVisitor.Visit(Expression node)
>      at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Query.EntityQueryModelVisitor.ReplaceClauseReferences(Expression expression, IQuerySource querySource, Boolean inProjection)
>      at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Query.RelationalQueryModelVisitor.CompileMainFromClauseExpression(MainFromClause mainFromClause, QueryModel queryModel)
>      at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Query.EntityQueryModelVisitor.VisitMainFromClause(MainFromClause fromClause, QueryModel queryModel)
>      at Remotion.Linq.QueryModelVisitorBase.VisitQueryModel(QueryModel queryModel)
>      at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Query.EntityQueryModelVisitor.VisitQueryModel(QueryModel queryModel)
>      at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Query.RelationalQueryModelVisitor.VisitQueryModel(QueryModel queryModel)
>      at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Query.EntityQueryModelVisitor.CreateAsyncQueryExecutor[TResult](QueryModel queryModel)
>      at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Query.Internal.CompiledQueryCache.GetOrAddQueryCore[TFunc](Object cacheKey, Func`1 compiler)
>      at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Query.Internal.QueryCompiler.ExecuteAsync[TResult](Expression query)
>      at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Query.Internal.EntityQueryable`1.System.Collections.Generic.IAsyncEnumerable<TResult>.GetEnumerator()
>      at System.Linq.AsyncEnumerable.Aggregate_[TSource,TAccumulate,TResult](IAsyncEnumerable`1 source, TAccumulate seed, Func`3 accumulator, Func`2 resultSelector, CancellationToken cancellationToken)

If I change DateTime to DateTimeOffset it works fine

Comment: Is the data null in the database?

Comment: Can you show the code that causes the error?

Comment: @bvoyelr in db field is not null

Comment: @TonyAbrams  dbContext.Prices.ToList()

Answer (score 0):

I'm sorry, but it was my mistake. We have own `EntityMaterializerSource`, that works incorrect. I'll close issue